# Why is my Python "if" condition not working

Tags: python, file, for-loop, if-statement, file-writing

I am writing a little utility that will read data from a pipe delimited file. If the 4th field in each row of the file is not empty, I want it write that row to another output file.

I am attempting to loop through each row in the input file, separate out the fields into a list, check to see if the 4th field (3rd index) value is NOT an empty string, and if so, write that row to another file.

Instead, it is writing every row of the original input file to the desired output file, even IF the 4th field (3rd index) value IS an empty string.

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
lines = src_file.readlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):    
    fields = lines[i].strip("\n").split("|")
   
    if fields[3] != '':
        lines[i] = "|".join(fields) + "\n"
    
 
src_file.close()
output_file = open(output_file_name, "w+")
output_file.writelines(lines)
output_file.close()
```

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: The canonical way of checking for not empty is just `if fields[3]:`.

Comment: You never remove the lines with empty 4th fields from the list.

Comment: `"|".join(fields) + "\n"` is the same as the original input line. You're not making any changes to the file.

Comment: @Barmar I think `for i in range...` is reasonable here, since the intent is to assign back to `lines[i]`.

Comment: @JohnGordon That's when I'd use `enumerate()`. But there isn't really a need to assign back to `lines[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never removing the lines with an empty field from `lines`.

You don't need to modify `lines[i]` (and you're not, since you're just joining `fields` back into the original string that it came from).

You should do the writing to the output file in the loop, so you can skip the lines that don't meet the condition.

```
with open(src_file_name) as src_file, open(output_file_name, "w") as output_file:
    for line in src_file:
        fields = line.strip("\n").split("|")
        if fields[3]:
            output_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like to skip a line if the 3rd index value is an empty string. So the condition should be exactly like "if the 3rd index value is an empty string skip the line".
I've edited your code, see if it works:

```py
lines = src_file.readlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):    
    fields = lines[i].strip("\n").split("|")
   
    if fields[3] == "":
        lines[i] = ""
    
src_file.close()

lines = [x for x in lines if x != ""]    #add this to skip the empty lines
output_file = open(output_file_name, "w+")
output_file.writelines(lines)
output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you are writing the whole lines into the new file; that's why the variable lines contain all the lines.

Here is working code:

```
output_file = open(output_file_name, "w+")
lines = src_file.readlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):    
    fields = lines[i].strip("\n").split("|")

    if fields[3] != '':
        output_file.write("|".join(fields) + "\n")

src_file.close()
output_file.close()
```